# How to find nodes within ways in Overpass QL?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a query which returns a number of `way`s. I want to find `node`s matching certain criteria which appear within those ways. Note that the nodes I'm interested in *do not* form part of the way itself, but do appear within the bounds of the way. Also, the ways do not all have corresponding areas, so using the area search doesn't work in all cases.

I've got a minimal example which finds way 95677318, and I want to be able to find node 1552949334:

```
(
  way({{bbox}})["man_made"="lighthouse"];
)->.searchArea;

/*doesn't work:*/
/*node(area.searchArea)["seamark:name"];*/

/*recur down and find node directly, just for the purpose of this question*/
(
  .searchArea;>;
  node({{bbox}})["seamark:name"];
);
out;
```

(Try it on https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/EpV)

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/67246/how-to-find-nodes-within-ways-in-overpass-ql

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet available as of release 0.7.55. In case there's no corresponding *area* available on the Overpass server, this kind of query is simply not feasible.

See https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/77 for details.